# Keep certain type on column and only one type on column in R?

Tags: r, row, columnsorting

I have a table which looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    "seqid" = c("12", "12", "13", "12", "12", "15"),
    "source" = c("star", "star", "star", "star", "star", "star"), 
    "type" = c("CDS", "CDS", "CDS", "intron", "CDS", "intron"),
    "start" = c("15", "21", "23", "35", "45", "60"), 
    "end" = c("70", "80", "86", "45", "67", "88"),
     "attributes" = c("ENSOCUT00000011013", "ENSOCUT00000064484", 
      "ENSOCUT00000013302", 
     "ENSOCUT00000010968", "ENSOCUT00000010968", "ENSOCUT00000060283"),
    stringsAsFactors = F,check.names=FALSE)
```

| seqid | source | Type | start | end | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | star | CDS | 15 | 70 | ENSOCUT00000011013 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 21 | 80 | ENSOCUT00000064484 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 23 | 86 | ENSOCUT00000013302 |
| 12 | star | intron | 35 | 45 | ENSOCUT00000010968 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 45 | 67 | ENSOCUT00000010968 |
| 12 | star | intron | 60 | 88 | ENSOCUT00000060283 |

I want my final result to look like this:

| seqid | source | Type | start | end | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | star | CDS | 15 | 70 | ENSOCUT00000011013 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 21 | 80 | ENSOCUT00000064484 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 23 | 86 | ENSOCUT00000013302 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 45 | 67 | ENSOCUT00000010968 |

So I want to group_by by only ENSOCUT00000011013, ENSOCUT00000064484, ENSOCUT00000013302, ENSOCUT00000010968 (on attributes column) and keep only the CDS of those on the type column

Comment: Try `df1 %>% filter(Type == 'CDS')` Or, if you need to group by `seqid` then: `df1 %>% group_by(seqid) %>% filter(Type == 'CDS')`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this, are you using a library for this as when I enter the first command it gives: Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'Type' not found
ℹ Input `..1` is `Type == "CDS"`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>

Comment: I need to group by the four names on the attributes and only keep CDS from the source column for those

Comment: yes load 'dplyr` library.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not solve how I can group_by  by only ENSOCUT00000011013, ENSOCUT00000064484, ENSOCUT00000013302, ENSOCUT00000010968 and keep only the CDS of those on the type column